# I want to get the title attribute from an image and add it to the surrounding link

Tags: jquery, attributes, fancybox, title, attr

So far I have this:

```
var imageTitle = $("a.articleimages img").attr("title");

$('a.articleimages').attr('title', (imageTitle));
```

The problem is it takes the first image's title and repeats it on every link. I can pull it off with IDs but it creates a lot of code because you have #image1, then #image2 and so on. Which to me seems excessive and stupid there must be an easier/better way. Maybe there is some way for it to know which image has been clicked and pull the title from that.

I want to do this so users don't have to retype an image title for it to be seen on Fancybox.

If there is a way to alter fancybox and get it to grab the thumbnail image title and show that for the full size image then I’d be happy with that too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `img` is a child of the `a` that you want to set the `title` for you could try something like this:

```
$('a.articleimages img').each(function(idx, element) {
   $(element).parent().attr('title',$(element).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: You get the accepted answer I decided to pick at random since there are so many answers that work. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a.articleimages img").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.parent().attr('title', $this.attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgs = $("a.articleimages img");

imgs.each(function(i, ele){
    var img = $(ele);
    var title = img.attr('title');
    img.parent('a').attr('title', title);
});
```

Comment: First thing I tried to do but apparently I need 15 reputation, so it won't let me. One day when I get 15 reputation I will come back and you will get the vote up that you truly deserve.